# Disassemble in the middle of an instruction with gdb?

Tags: gdb

I believe this worked perfectly previously, but maybe I just forgot the correct syntax.

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001125 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000000000001126 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000001129 <+4>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
   0x000000000000112c <+7>: mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
   0x0000000000001130 <+11>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000001135 <+16>:    pop    rbp
   0x0000000000001136 <+17>:    ret
```

Now I want to disassemble at 0x0000000000001127, which is 1 byte into the first mov instruction:

```
(gdb) disas 0x0000000000001127
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001125 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000000000001126 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000001129 <+4>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
   0x000000000000112c <+7>: mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
   0x0000000000001130 <+11>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000001135 <+16>:    pop    rbp
   0x0000000000001136 <+17>:    ret
```

It still starts the disassembly at the top of main.

I've also tried things such as main+1, disas /r, etc. Did gdb's behavior change somehow? I thought perhaps it was related to this being a PIE binary, but when I recompile it with -no-pie I still have this problem for something so simple.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It still starts the disassembly at the top of main.

When you give `disas` a single argument, it finds the enclosing function, and disassembles that *entire* function. This has been the behavior since forever.

If you give `disas` two arguments instead, then it will disassemble just the given range:

```
(gdb) disas &main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000000005fa <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000000005fb <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000000005fe <+4>: mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000000603 <+9>: pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000000604 <+10>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) disas &main+3,&main+11
Dump of assembler code from 0x5fd to 0x605:
   0x00000000000005fd <main+3>: in     $0xb8,%eax
   0x00000000000005ff <main+5>: add    %al,(%rax)
   0x0000000000000601 <main+7>: add    %al,(%rax)
   0x0000000000000603 <main+9>: pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000000604 <main+10>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

You could also use `x/i`:

```
(gdb) x/4i &main+3
   0x5fd <main+3>:  in     $0xb8,%eax
   0x5ff <main+5>:  add    %al,(%rax)
   0x601 <main+7>:  add    %al,(%rax)
   0x603 <main+9>:  pop    %rbp
```